# cannot create parpool in matlab in slurm, ubuntu16.04 server

Tags: matlab, slurm

I have some trouble on creating parpool in matlab in slurm

when I submit the job, it will get stuck :

parpool size: 24

```
Starting parallel pool (parpool) using the 'local' profile ...

or error

{Error using parpool (line 104)
Failed to start a parallel pool. (For information in addition to the causing
error, validate the profile 'local' in the Cluster Profile Manager.)


Error in run (line 86)
evalin('caller', [script ';']);

Caused by:
    Error using parallel.internal.pool.InteractiveClient>iThrowWithCause (line
    666)
    Failed to initialize the interactive session.
        Error using
        parallel.internal.pool.InteractiveClient>iThrowIfBadParallelJobStatus
        (line 767)
        The interactive communicating job failed with no message.
}
```

There is also a matlab crash dump file

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
       Segmentation violation detected at Sun Apr  2 11:36:33 2017
------------------------------------------------------------------------

Configuration:
  Crash Decoding      : Disabled - No sandbox or build area path
  Crash Mode          : continue (default)
  Default Encoding    : UTF-8
  GNU C Library       : 2.23 stable
  Host Name           : wmc-slave-g2
  MATLAB Architecture : glnxa64
  MATLAB Root         : /opt/matlab/R2017a
  MATLAB Version      : 9.2.0.538062 (R2017a)
  Operating System    : Linux 4.4.0-66-generic #87-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 3 15:29:05 UTC 2017 x86_64
  Processor ID        : x86 Family 6 Model 79 Stepping 1, GenuineIntel

Fault Count: 1


Abnormal termination:
Segmentation violation

Register State (from fault):
  RAX = 00007f7410256900  RBX = 0000000000000000
  RCX = 0000000000000000  RDX = 00007f7410256978
  RSP = 00007f741e240868  RBP = 00007f741e240870
  RSI = 0000000000000000  RDI = 00007f741e240870

   R8 = 0000000000000000   R9 = 0000000000000000
  R10 = 00000000000000ed  R11 = 00007f743afade60
  R12 = 00007f7410256978  R13 = 00007f741e2408a0
  R14 = 00007f741e2409f0  R15 = 00007f7410258110

  RIP = 00007f743afade60  EFL = 0000000000010202

   CS = 0033   FS = 0000   GS = 0000

Stack Trace (from fault):
[  0] 0x00007f743afade60 /opt/matlab/R2017a/bin/glnxa64/libboost_thread.so.1.56.0+00069216 _ZNK5boost6thread15get_thread_infoEv+00000000
[  1] 0x0000000000000000                                   <unknown-module>+00000000
```

If this problem is reproducible, please submit a Service Request via:

A technical support engineer might contact you with further information.

Thanks

Comment: What command did you issue to create the parallel pool in Matlab. IIRC, you need a special license for parallel processing in Matlab. Does your license permit the operation you are attempting?

Comment: j= str2num(getenv('SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK'));
    fprintf('parpool size: %d\n', j);

Comment: This codes went well before yesterday, so I think the license is ok. Furthermore, I find it can start parpool well in the conpute node separately，but when submit a job, it gets stuck.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually due to java version incompatibility used for Matlab on Linux. issue:

`echo $MATLAB_JAVA`

If this variable set, you can unset this option and let Matlab use its own java. you can run a script like this:

`#!/bin/sh
    unset MATLAB_JAVA
    matlab -desktop`